# WebSphere Dynacache Thread Blocking

Tags: caching, websphere, websphere-7

I am running a web application on WebSphere Application Server 7.0.0.37 that uses IBM's DynaCache to store data for dropdown lists. When I add load to the code that iterates the list, I end up seeing threads blocking from an analysis of the heap.

Here is the code that retrieves the DistributedMap. Note, I'm not caching the InitialContext as IBM noted it gets cached for you; however, I will be testing with it still to see if it fixes the issue I'm having.

```
public PinqCache() {
    if (getProviderTypeSpecialtyMap() != null) {
        getProviderTypeSpecialtyMap().clear();
    }
}

public DistributedMap getProviderTypeSpecialtyMap() {
    return getDistributedMapByName("/services/cache/provTypeSpecialty");
}

private DistributedMap getDistributedMapByName(String name) {
    InitialContext ic;
    DistributedMap dm = null;
    try {
        ic = new InitialContext();
        dm = (DistributedMap) ic.lookup(name);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dm;
}
```

When I view the thread analysis from IBM's thread analysis tool, I see that 41 threads are being blocked. Here is a stack trace from one of the blocked threads:

```
Thread Name = WebContainer : 3758
State = Blocked
Monitor = Waiting for Monitor Lock on com/ibm/ws/naming/jcache/Cache@0x0000000041FDBCC0/0x0000000041FDBCCC
Java Stack = 
at com/ibm/ws/naming/jcache/Cache.bind(Cache.java:374(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/naming/jndicos/CNContextImpl.processResolveResults(CNContextImpl.java:3738(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/naming/jndicos/CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1861(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/naming/jndicos/CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1762(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/naming/jndicos/CNContextImpl.lookupExt(CNContextImpl.java:1513(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/naming/jndicos/CNContextImpl.lookup(CNContextImpl.java:645(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/naming/util/WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:166(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/naming/util/WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:180(Compiled Code)) 
at javax/naming/InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436(Compiled Code)) 
at PinqCache.getDistributedMapByName(PinqCache.java:32(Compiled Code))
```

There are different API methods that are showing blocks:

```
com/ibm/ws/naming/jcache/Cache.lookup
com/ibm/ws/naming/jcache/Cache.bind
com/ibm/ws/naming/jcache/Cache.setLifetimeProperties
```

My question is, what would cause this situation where threads are blocking when calling the InitialContext.lookup?

--- UPDATE ---

I've added the thread that owns the monitor lock.

```
    Thread Name = WebContainer : 3709
    State = Waiting on Condition
    Monitor = Owns Monitor Lock on com/ibm/ws/naming/jcache/Cache@0x0000000041FDBCC0/0x0000000041FDBCCC
    Java Stack = 
at com/ibm/ws/naming/jcache/Cache.getParentContext(Cache.java:1003(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/naming/jcache/Cache.bind(Cache.java:382(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/naming/jndicos/CNContextImpl.processResolveResults(CNContextImpl.java:3738(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/naming/jndicos/CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1861(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/naming/jndicos/CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1762(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/naming/jndicos/CNContextImpl.lookupExt(CNContextImpl.java:1513(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/naming/jndicos/CNContextImpl.lookup(CNContextImpl.java:645(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/naming/util/WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:166(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/naming/util/WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:180(Compiled Code)) 
at javax/naming/InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436(Compiled Code)) 
at com/hcsc/rtb/fs/DAO/pinqDs/PinqCache.getDistributedMapByName(PinqCache.java:32(Compiled Code))
```

--- UPDATE 2 ---

I was able to capture information from the JNDI trace. I've included some of it that I felt was relevant; however, there is obviously a lot more in here.

I'm consistently seeing the exception below. I've had to *** out the cluster name for privacy.

```
[10/12/16 14:22:59:986 CDT] 00000084 CNContextImpl >  getNameInNamespace Entry
[10/12/16 14:22:59:986 CDT] 00000084 CNContextImpl <  getNameInNamespace Exit ********
[10/12/16 14:22:59:986 CDT] 00000084 NameSpace     3   lookupInternal
                                 lookupInternal, nsID=10, name=: this=com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace@1c781c78[_nameSpaceID=10, _nameSpaceType=2, _contextsTable=java.util.HashMap@a5c8e52d[size=9], _bindingsTable=java.util.HashMap@7cd83d3c[size=24]], currContext=com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl@27442744[contextID=t-shrdm-was70-2Cell01/clusters/rtb_uat2, nameInNamespace=********]
[10/12/16 14:22:59:986 CDT] 00000084 NameSpace     3   validateName
                                 Name is null or empty.
[10/12/16 14:22:59:987 CDT] 00000084 Cache         3   getParentContext
                                 javax.naming.InvalidNameException: A null or empty name is not allowed.
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.validateName(NameSpace.java:1632)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookupInternal(NameSpace.java:1115)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.intermediateCacheLookup(NameSpace.java:1101)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jcache.Cache.getParentContext(Cache.java:943)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jcache.Cache.bind(Cache.java:382)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.processResolveResults(CNContextImpl.java:3738)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1861)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1762)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookupExt(CNContextImpl.java:1513)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookup(CNContextImpl.java:645)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:166)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:180)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436)
```

Comment: What thread holds the lock?

Comment: I've added the thread that owns the monitor lock to the OP. I'm not sure with IBM's tool to see why its waiting.

Comment: Can you follow the instructions here to get a dumpNameSpace and JNDI trace? https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21143296  Is this a clustered or single JVM environment? If clustered what is the topology?

Comment: Alexandre, I'm going to run a performance test tomorrow morning and will ask to have this captured. Thanks!

Comment: I'll update the ticket with the JNDI trace I captured.

Comment: Also it is clustered. Its two physical servers each running one JVM.